# How to save image width and height from onload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an array of `<li>` elements that I am trying to make into a carousel, just that I want the images to be resized if bigger than 640x480 as well as centered into the frame.

I have the following code:
HTML:

```
<ul id="carousel">      
    <li><img src="pic1.jpg" /><p><b>2012</b> something</p></li>
    <li><img src="pic2.jpg" /><p><b>2016</b> something else.</p></li>
</ul>
```

JQuery:

```
var imW=[];
var imH=[];
//...
$('li',obj).each(function(index){ 
    itemSources.push( $(this).find('img').attr('src') );                
    var img = $(this).find('img'); 
    imW.push(img.width());
    imH.push(img.height());
});
```

I then use `itemSources[i]`, `imW[i]` and `imH[i]` to resize my image and add any necessary padding to center it in the frame.

Which works fine provided that my internet is fast enough and the images load before the size is computed. (ha!)

I know I want something like:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    console.log(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
};
img.src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
```

But I cannot save the width and height, since just pushing to the arrays gets out of scope, and so does creating an external callback for that. How can I save those sizes that are so easily printed to the console into my imW and imH arrays?

Comment: what do you need to do with those values after putting them in an array?

Comment: you can basically set an attribute of an image, something like `data-loaded="true" ` once the image is loaded and when the last image is loaded you can then iterate the images and load the array

Comment: I am using them when I render my carousel to resize the image and add padding (left/top) so that if one of the image dimensions is smaller, the image is displayed centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can basically set an attribute of an image, something like `data-loaded="true"` once the image is loaded and when the last image is loaded you can then iterate the images and load the array

In your `onload` method, do the following changes

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    console.log(this.width + 'x' + this.height);

    //set this attribute to indicate that this image has been loaded already
    $(this).attr( "data-loaded", "true" );

    //check if all images have this attribute
    if ( $( "img[data-loaded='true']" ).size() == $( "img" ).size() ) 
    {
      //now iterate the images to load your array
    }
};
img.src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, ended up just waiting for all the images to load before loading the window with `$(window).on("load", function() { `, though it's sort of apparent that something is happening...